How to set text color of DatePicker to White?
I'm using a previous question on Stackoverflow for implementing Wheel Date picker using DatePicker of View library in jetpack compose.
The result i have before navigating to next page.

After i navigate to next page and come back to the dateOfbirth page this is the result i get

The date_picker.xml
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/datePicker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black"
android:calendarTextColor="#FFFFFF"
android:calendarViewShown="false"
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
android:theme="@style/CustomDatePickerStyle" />

AndroidView
@Composable
fun DatePicker(
    onDateSelected: (Date) -> Unit
) {

AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    factory = { context ->
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.date_picker, null)
        val datePicker = view.findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.datePicker)
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance() // show today by default
        datePicker.init(
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ) { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            val date = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
            }.time
            onDateSelected(date)

        }
        datePicker
    }
)
}

This is how i'm using it
DatePicker { date ->
            validationViewModel.changeDateOfBirth(date)
}

This is validationViewModel
/** Date of Birth Validation */
var dateOfBirth by mutableStateOf(Date())
    private set

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
val dateOfBirthError = snapshotFlow { dateOfBirth }
    .mapLatest { validateAge.execute(dateOfBirth.toString().substring(30)) }
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = ValidationResult()
    )

fun changeDateOfBirth(value: Date) {
    dateOfBirth = value
}

Theme.kt
private val colorScheme = lightColorScheme(
primary = green, // Your custom green color
onPrimary = Color.White, // Black text on green buttons
secondary = Color.White,
background = Color.Black,
onBackground = Color.White,
surface = Color.Black,
onSurface = Color.White
)

@Composable
fun SpotifyTheme(
content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
   val colorScheme = colorScheme


MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    typography = Typography,
    content = content
)
}


This usually happens when you are using dark theme inside your compose theme. Check your Theme.kt file and see which color scheme is being applied to your app.

@AhsanZia thanks, i add my theme.kt on question. I only want to have one theme with dark theme

To add only dark theme in your app you just need to change the lightColorScheme to darkColorScheme as shown below
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
primary = green, // Your custom green color
onPrimary = Color.White, // Black text on green buttons
secondary = Color.White,
background = Color.Black,
onBackground = Color.White,
surface = Color.Black,
onSurface = Color.White
)

Then finally you can use this dark theme inside your Material theme.
MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = DarkColorScheme,
    typography = Typography,
    content = content
)


Thanks for your time, i tried it but still facing the same problem.
